# convert SQL to LINQ (max and replace)

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq

Please help me convert SQL to LINQ

```
MAX(Convert (int, left(REPLACE(REPLACE(sohoso,'GM/Q5/',''),'GM/Q8'),5)))+1
```

```
select MAX([STT])+1
FROM [NangDoiNhanhGanMoi].[dbo].[CongTacGMND]
WHERE right(SoHoSo,4)=2020 and left(sohoso,2)='GM'
```

Thanks you

Comment: Whats your attempt so far? I think you can almost copy and paste the sql into LINQ.

Comment: Can you describe your query in words? My SQL is fairly rusty, So I hardly understand what this SQL query says.